# Obter e separar dados que não estão no array

Tags: php

Eu sei que utilizando `in_array`, eu checo se o valor existe no array.

Eu preciso saber se o `id`, contem números de 1 a 6.

Se algum número entre 1 e 6 existir, exibe a mensagem, `ID existe no array`, caso contrário eu preciso separar e armazenar em variáveis os `IDs`que não foram encontrados.

```
public function atualizar_menu($dados)
{
    $array = (array)$dados;
    foreach ($dados as $mnu){
        $menu = array(
            'id'            => $mnu->id,
            'permissao_id'  => $mnu->permissao_id,
            'padrao'        => $mnu->padrao,                
        );
        print_r($menu);

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
            if(in_array($i, $menu))
            {
                echo 'ID '.$i.' existe no Array.<br>';
            }
        }
    }//Fim do foreach
}
```

Comment: Bem confuso seu código. O valor de `$dados` é um *array* de objetos e você quer saber se em algum desses objetos há um `id` entre 1 e 6? Se sim, tem forma bem mais simples de fazer isso.

Comment: Além de saber se existe algum ID entre 1 e 6 no array, quero obter os ID que não está no array.
Exemplo: `1, 2 e 3 estão no array e 4,5 e 6 não estão.`

Answer (score 0):

```
(...)
for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
  if(in_array($i, $menu)){
    echo 'ID '.$i.' existe no Array.<br>';

    if($menu->id >= 1 && $menu->id <= 6){
      //Descarrega o código aqui! =D
    }
  }
}
```

(..)

Comment: Valeu pela identação! =D

Sou novo aqui, não acostumei ainda... ¬¬

Comment: Mas tambem não deu certo. `Message: Undefined offset: 1`
E desta forma, não consigo saber qual ID não está no array.

Comment: Foi mal de novo, coloca dentro do if que tu verifica a existência

Comment: Aínda assim erro de offset

Comment: exatamente onde?

rodei um loop aqui só nessa parte e funcionou...

Comment: Exatamente aqui: ` if($menu[$i] -> id >= 1 && $menu[$i] -> id <= 6){`

Comment: ¬¬ não tem um array de $menu então é só $menu->id, equivocos... :x

Comment: Sim, e mas está dentro do foreach `$mnu->id`.
O que eu queria era saber quais IDs não está no array.

Comment: É eu vi, tipo o $mnu é um array, o $menu não, então não tem indexação, agora, se tu rodar do jeito que está lá, ele vai verificar se existe, depois verificar se está entre 1 e 6, e dentro do if do entre 1 e 6 tu faz a separação...